# ViewAction microdata not showing CTA button in GMail

Tags: gmail, html-email, google-schemas

I'm trying to add a [GMail "Go-To Action"](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/go-to-action#microdata) CTA button in an email with the following code:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/EmailMessage">
  <meta itemprop="description" content="Activate Your Account" />
  <div itemprop="potentialAction" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ViewAction">
    <link itemprop="target" href="https://path.to/activate" />
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Activate Account" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried using both `target` (as above) and `url` itemprops, as I see elsewhere that there might be some confusion between docs and reality, and have even tried adding them both. When I click to "Show original" in GMail I see what is shown below but no button is displayed in the inbox.

```
----==_mimepart_abc123
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/EmailMessage">
  <meta itemprop="description" content="Activate Your Account">
  <div itemprop="potentialAction" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ViewAction">
    <link itemprop="target" href="https://path.to/activate">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Activate Account">
  </div>
</div>
target only
</body></html>

----==_mimepart_abc123
```

Comment: is this AMP email? Because this look like nothing like what you would normally put in an email

Comment: @Nathan https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/go-to-action#microdata_1

Answer (score 1):

Have you contacted google for approval of the CTA button? This is a crucial step in displaying the button on Gmail.

Comment: Yes, they referred me here :)